# Accessing global resources in App.xaml from ContentView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a color defined in my App.xaml resource dictionary. When I try to reference it in a ContentView I get a run time exception:

> StaticResource not found for key NavbarBackground

Do I need to merge the resource dictionary in App.xaml?

App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!--Global Styles-->
        ...
        <Color x:Key="NavbarBackground">Black</Color>
        ...
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

CustomTitleView.xaml

```
<ContentView>
    ...
    <ContentView.Content>
         ...
                <ImageButton Source="search.png" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource NavbarBackground}" />
         ...
     </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: You don't need to merge anything. This should be working. Try deleting the bin/obj folders and rebuilding.

Comment: This should be working +1 ,refer to this sample : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries#create-resources-in-xaml

Comment: Did you try to define the color with a hexadecimal code? After that, rebuild your solution. There is no problem with your code.

Comment: All I did was change StaticResource to DynamicResource and now it works. Still not entirely clear what the difference is or why this worked but in any case this seems to do the trick.

Comment: Check the [differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/dynamic) between StaticResource  and DynamicResource  ,they are almost the same but DynamicResource   would change if the value associated is replaced in dictionary , however , you could use both of them . It is weird that why `StaticResource ` not work here .

Answer (score -1):

If you are using separate xaml file to define resources use ResourceDictionary. If you are settings values inside App.xaml set them inside Application.Resources. Refer to docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries)

Comment: So in my ContentView I changed StaticResource NavbarBackground to DynamicResource NavbarBackground and that seems to have worked. Still not entirely clear why this was required.